# Selenium div attributes keep changing, how can I find this element?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to find an element with Selenium and Java, the problem is that the element's id, class, and name always increment so I am not able to find it with selenium. Below is what I am currently trying:

```
WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@linkText, 'Broadcast copy')]"));
```

In my html file these are the attributes that keeps changing:

```
id="files[%2Fopt%240%2Frules%2F%2F000102%2.xml][%2Fcluster%2Fname]"

name="files[%2Fopt%240%2Frules%2F%2F000102%2.xml][%2Fcluster%2Fname]" 

value="copy (Cluster 102)"
```

**Entire html**

```
<tbody>
   <tr class='rowOdd'>
      <td><b>Name</b></td>
      <td> <input type='text' data-validation='required validate-name-unique validate-name-not-empty' size='65' id='files[%2Fopt%240%2Frules%2F%2F000102%2Fcluster.xml][%2Fcluster%2Fname]' name='files[%2Fopt%240%2Frules%2F%2F000102%2Fcluster.xml][%2Fcluster%2Fname]' value='copy (Cluster 102)' /> </td>
```

These always increment and I have no access to the html file to change anything. So my question is how can I find this input element? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I get the error:

```
Unable to locate element:{"method":"id", "selector":"files[.*][.*]"}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `html` with parent node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the attributes of id, class, and css were constantly changing, 'data-validation' was one that stayed the same all the time. So the code below worked for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-validation='required validate-name-unique validate-name-not-empty']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the xpath you are using is incorrect. Use

```
//input[contains(text(), 'Broadcast copy')]
```

instead of

```
//input[contains(@linkText, 'Broadcast copy')]
```

According to the html you have provide the following should work as well

```
//body[contains(.,'Name')]//input
```

Comment: Is the element inside any iframe then?

Comment: No just inside a table inside a regular div tag. Can it be because it is writing to an xml file? If so how can I find this element? Thanks.

Comment: Inside the input id there is an ".xml" extension. My question was, can this be why selenium is not finding the element?

Comment: I have never dealt with anything like that. Do you mean xml nested in html?

Comment: I think so, it seems the id is the file to where html is writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

In case "**copy (Cluster**" text in value attribute is not changing, then you can try below xpath:-

```
 //body[contains(.,'Name')]//input[contains(@value,'copy (Cluster')]
```