# how to scrape data from shopee using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently a student where currently I studied beautifulsoup so my lecturer as me to scrape data from shopee however I cannot scrape the details of the products. Currently, I'm trying to scrape data from https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales. I only want to scrape the name and price of the products. can someone tell me why I cannot scrape the data using beautifulsoup ?

Here is my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales"
response= get (url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
print (soup)
```

Comment: add code snippet what you have tried so far,otherwise how would someone help you

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO please add what you have tried so far input & expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance @RajuBhaya

Comment: @Ana you can check my answer, mnm also correctly stated the Dom element. I added both selenium and beautifulsoup way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is a bit tricky (*for python beginners*) because it involves a combination of selenium (for headless browsing) and beautifulsoup (for html data extraction). Moreover, the problem becomes difficult because the Document Object Model (DOM) is encased within javascripting. We know javascript is there because we get an empty response from the website when accessed only using beautifulsoup, like, `for item_n in soup.find_all('div', class_='_1NoI8_ _16BAGk'):
            print(item_n.get_text())`

Therefore, to extract data from such a webpage which has a scripting language controlling its DOM, we have to use selenium for headless browsing (*this tells the website that a browser is accessing it*). We also have to use some sort of delay parameter, (*which tells the website that it's accessed by a human*). For this, the function `WebdriverWait()` from the selenium library will help.

I now present snippets of code that explain the process.

First, import the requisite libraries

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
```

Next, initialize the settings for the headless browser. I'm using chrome.

```
# create object for chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
base_url = 'https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales'

# set chrome driver options to disable any popup's from the website
# to find local path for chrome profile, open chrome browser
# and in the address bar type, "chrome://version"
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default')
# To disable the message, "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    })
# invoke the webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/username/Documents/playground_python/chromedriver.exe',
                          options = chrome_options)
browser.get(base_url)
delay = 5 #secods
```

Next, I declare empty list variables to hold the data.

```
# declare empty lists
item_cost, item_init_cost, item_loc = [],[],[]
item_name, items_sold, discount_percent = [], [], []
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, delay)
        print ("Page is ready")
        sleep(5)
        html = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
        #print(html)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        # find_all() returns an array of elements. 
        # We have to go through all of them and select that one you are need. And than call get_text()
        for item_n in soup.find_all('div', class_='_1NoI8_ _16BAGk'):
            print(item_n.get_text())
            item_name.append(item_n.text)

        # find the price of items
        for item_c in soup.find_all('span', class_='_341bF0'):
            print(item_c.get_text())
            item_cost.append(item_c.text)

        # find initial item cost
        for item_ic in soup.find_all('div', class_ = '_1w9jLI QbH7Ig U90Nhh'):
            print(item_ic.get_text())
            item_init_cost.append(item_ic.text)
        # find total number of items sold/month
        for items_s in soup.find_all('div',class_ = '_18SLBt'):
            print(items_s.get_text())
            items_sold.append(item_ic.text)

        # find item discount percent
        for dp in soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'percent'):
            print(dp.get_text())
            discount_percent.append(dp.text)
        # find item location
        for il in soup.find_all('div', class_ = '_3amru2'):
            print(il.get_text())
            item_loc.append(il.text)

        break # it will break from the loop once the specific element will be present. 
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!-Try again")
```

Thereafter, I use the `zip` function to combine the different list items.

```
rows = zip(item_name, item_init_cost,discount_percent,item_cost,items_sold,item_loc)
```

Finally, I write this data to disc,

```
import csv
newFilePath = 'shopee_item_list.csv'
with open(newFilePath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

As a good practice, its wise to close the headless browser once the task is complete. And so i code it as,

```
# close the automated browser
browser.close()
```

Result

```
Nestle MILO Activ-Go Chocolate Malt Powder (2kg)
NESCAFE GOLD Refill (170g)
Nestle MILO Activ-Go Chocolate Malt Powder (1kg)
MAGGI Hot Cup - Asam Asam Laksa (60g)
MAGGI 2-Minit Curry (79g x 5 Packs x 2)
MAGGI PAZZTA Cheese Macaroni 70g
.......
29.90
21.90
16.48
1.69
8.50
3.15
5.90
.......
RM40.70
RM26.76
RM21.40
RM1.80
RM9.62
........
9k sold/month
2.3k sold/month
1.8k sold/month
1.7k sold/month
.................
27%
18%
23%
6%
.............
Selangor
Selangor
Selangor
Selangor
```

**Note to the readers**

The OP brought to my attention that the xpath was not working as given in my answer. I checked the website again after 2 days and noticed a strange phenomenon. The `class_` attribute of the `div` class had indeed changed. I found a [similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407402/selenium-div-attributes-keep-changing-how-can-i-find-this-element). But it did not help much. So for now, I'm concluding the div attributes in the shoppee website can change again. I leave this as an open problem to solve later.

**Note to the OP**

Ana, the above code will work for just one page i.e., it will work only for the webpage, `https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales`. I invite you to further enhance your skills by solving how to scrape data for multiple webpages under the sales tag. Your hint is the `1/9` seen on the top right of the this page and/or the `1 2 3 4 5` links at the bottom of the page. Another hint for you is to look at the urljoin in the urlparse library. Hope this should get you started.

**Helpful resources**

- [XPATH tutorial](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance and I want to ask for  this part--> chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default') I already changed to my local path of chrome however it displayed like this -->
    chrome_options.add_argument('C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default')
                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape  so can u tell me where im wrong for this part. sorry for disturb you again

Comment: @Ana, I'm happy to help beginners out. You have to develop a mindset of asking Qs but refrain yourself from apologizing to everyone. Your a beginner and we know that. Your bound to make mistakes and its normal. We all commit mistakes at some point of time. With that said, if you notice, I used double backslash \\ in my code while you have used a single backslash \ and thus the error. The error is telling you that it cant understand \. Because, it only understands \\. So the Q is **Why \\ than \?**. The answer is, using double backslash in directory path helps in escaping unicode characterset.

Comment: so change the line in your code `C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` to this `C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default`. Try it, if does not work then I'll suggest just comment this line of code.

Comment: thanks. it works perfectly however for the name of the products it only displayed 1 product ...

Comment: @Ana can you show me the code you execute for getting products info?

Comment: here is my coding-->  for item_n in soup.find_all('div', class_='_1NoI8_ _16BAGk'):
            print(item_n.get_text())
            item_name.append(item_n.text)

Comment: @Ana, change the product value `class_` from `_1NoI8_ _16BAGk` to `_1NoI8_ _1JBBaM`  You will get all products listing. Check and let me know

Comment: @Ana I have revised the same in my answer.

Comment: @Ana you are welcome. I recommend that you read this guideline on [What should you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Cant scrape the whole page of 50 products on a headless browser.

Answer (score 2):

The page is loading after the first request sends to the page by ajax async so sending one request and getting the source of the page you want seems not possible.

You should simulate a browser then you can get the source and you can use the beautifulsoup. See the code:

### BeautifulSoup way

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver.get("https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.shop-search-result-view')))

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
search = soup.select_one('.shop-search-result-view')
products = search.find_all('a')

for p in products:
    name = p.select('div[data-sqe="name"] > div')[0].get_text()
    price = p.select('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)')[0].get_text()
    product = p.select('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4)')[0].get_text()
    print('name: ' + name)
    print('price: ' + price)
    print('product: ' + product + '\n')
```

However, using selenium is a good approach to get everything you want. See the example below:

### Selenium Way

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://shopee.com.my/shop/13377506/search?page=0&sortBy=sales")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.shop-search-result-view')))

search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.shop-search-result-view')
products = search.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')

for p in products:
    name = p.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-sqe="name"] > div').text
    price = p.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)').text
    product = p.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4)').text
    print('name: ' + name)
    print('price: ' + price.replace('\n', ' | '))
    print('product: ' + product + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

please post your code so we can help.

or you can start like this.. :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReg


my_url = "<url>"
uClient = uReg(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
```

Comment: don't post incomplete answers. I understand your trying to help the OP but what you've posted does not essentially help much. Ideally, you should have given this help in the form of comments! Get my point?

Comment: thanks for ur advice sorry I'm still new in this so I'm kind of blur what should I do  @mnm

Comment: @Ana I can explain the answer to you but I cannot because this question is now closed and is not accepting any answers. If you are still interested to know and learn, then I'll recommend that you **Ask a New Q**. I'll also recommend that you look into `selinium` library for browser automation. This library holds the key to your problem. When you ask the new Q tag me in it using @mnm so that I'll be notified. Pls show some effort in the new Q like you referenced existing posts related to your Q and where are you now stuck at. Hope this helps.

Comment: @mnm i have created new question regarding this > https://stackoverflow.com/q/62145548/13632126

Comment: @Ana, I noticed the other Q was removed. And I also found that this original Q, was opened again. So, I have posted my answer. Hope this helps.