# How to scrape information inside an unordered list selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraping project, where I try to scrape information from the amazon website. In the website, there exists an unordered list with such information

```
Item Weight: 17.2 pounds
Shipping Weight: 17.4 pounds (View shipping rates and policies)
ASIN: B00HC767P6
UPC: 766789717088 885720483186 052000201628
Item model number: mark-1hooi-toop842
Customer Reviews: 4.8 out of 5 stars1,352 customer ratings
Amazon Best Sellers Rank: #514 in Grocery & Gourmet Food (See Top 100 in Grocery & Gourmet Food)
#12 in Sports Drinks
```

The list itself does not have any class to it. The problem is I do not want all the information from the list. Only the ASIN code. the `li` tags do not have any specific class or ID to them. here is the link to the [product details page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKN2ZT9)

Before selenium, I was working with BeautifulSoup and this is how I tackled the issue

```
asin = str(soup.find('bdi', {'dir': 'ltr'}).find_parent('li'))[38:].split('<')[0]
```

I am now switching to selenium. How do I scrape the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css selector to get the related li item as follow:

### Finding the child element by index by css selector

```
$(".content > ul > li:nth-child(2)").textContent >>> "Shipping Weight: 33 pounds (View shipping rates and policies)"
$(".content > ul > li:nth-child(3)").textContent >>> "ASIN: B07QKN2ZT9"
```

related python selenium code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".content > ul > li:nth-child(3)").text.split(": ")[1] >>> 'B07QKN2ZT9'
```

### Finding the ancestors element by XPATH

If the ASIN is not always in the same index, then you can find the `bdi` element that has text `ASIN` text and find its `ancestor::li` then get its text and extract the related part. Like the following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::li").text.split(": ")[1] >>> 'B07QKN2ZT9'
```

#### Generate XPATH

```
//<element type>[<attribute type> = <attribute value>]/<descendant>
//bdi[text() = 'ASIN'] >>> bdi element with text 'ASIN'
//bdi[@dir = 'ltr'] >>> bdi element with dir attribute equals to 'ltr'
```

#### Access to an ancestor of an element

```
/ancestor::<ancestor element type>
//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::li >>> li
//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::ul >>> ul
```

[image: accessing ancestor of an element]

You can check [this as a reference](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: Hi. While this answer works, the `asin` field might not always be the 3rd element in the list. That is the problem with this. sometimes it might also be the 2nd element and sometimes the 4th. I will need to access only that field in all cases...

Comment: @Sashaank this was not mentioned but updated the solution you can check it

Comment: Thanks a lot. this code works like a charm. I will have to start learning xpath more properly now. If it is possible can you point me to some good tutorial on xpath?

Comment: added a reference

Comment: @MesutGUNES what is `>>>` ? in fact, pls can you explain this entire line of code `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::li").text.split(": ")[1] >>> 'B07QKN2ZT9'`in terms of what is it doing?

Comment: >>> add to refer what it prints out or what it means, sorry for unclarity. @mnm see the updated part of the answer

Comment: @MesutGUNES thank you for taking the time to answer. It clears my doubt now. I take this opportunity to indulge you in [another Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057645/how-to-scrape-data-from-shopee-using-beautiful-soup/62148452?noredirect=1#comment110030477_62148452) that I recently answered. The problem is the attribute keeps changing for the div class. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it?